# Docx conversion

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am doing simple docx conversion app in android.

```
File file = new File(path + "Sample1.docx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

 XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument( fis);
 XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);  
 String docText = extractor.getText();
```

Added the above line in my onCreate method.

Included dom4j,poi3.8,poi-ooxml3.8,poi-xml-schema3.8 & xmlbeans jars in libs folder.

When i run this i got the error  **Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536**

Googled and i got the info about converting jar to dex.

With out dex is that possible docx reading? Even i dont want xlsx & pptx packages of poi.

I want covert only doc and docx file. Is there any separate code for only doc&docx conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make [JWord](http://www.independentsoft.com) working under Android. Had many issues with Apache POI like you have (Conversion to Dalvik format failed).