# Read DOCx,PPTx,XLSx Files from Android using Apache POI libs - Android

Tags: android, ms-office, apache-poi

I am creating android app that is reading microsoft files without any third party application, I have used Apache POI lib. for reading/Open office files , I am able to open doc,ppt and xls file but not able to open DOCx,PPTx,XLSx , I had tried below code to read

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.FILEPATH)));
        // getResources().getAssets().open("doc2.doc");

        XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);

        xwpfDocument.getXWPFDocument();
        xwpfDocument.getBodyElements();
```

It throws exception as below

```
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at      org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:154)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:121)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.narola.yujidownloader.OfficeActivity.populateWordX(OfficeActivity.java:605)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.narola.yujidownloader.OfficeActivity.populate(OfficeActivity.java:139)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.narola.yujidownloader.OfficeActivity.initialize(OfficeActivity.java:111)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.narola.yujidownloader.OfficeActivity.onCreate(OfficeActivity.java:96)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.dom4j.Namespace
04-08 05:34:20.407: E/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers.PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesUnmarshaller.java:49)
```

I have referred [Apchae POI docx](http://poi.apache.org/document/index.html)

Please guide me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488581/docx-conversion/18527938#18527938 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488581/docx-conversion/18527938#18527938

Comment: @Mich Its not working